# Access: Keep Only Rows with a Blank

Tags: ms-access, filter, blank-line

I have a report I'm developing for my company.  We have roughly 8 departments that associates MIGHT work in during the course of their day.  Some stay in only 1 department, others move around and on any given day that can change.  I have the report up and running and all is well.

HOWEVER...
We are seeing a major problem with people not clocking into the departments they travel to (we see where they do work in a department but have no time logged).  We understand that it's a training issue, but I have been tasked with creating a report to show those people that miss a clock in when changing departments.

I am not an Access Guru, but I have moderate experience with it.  I'm struggling though to come up with a way to show ONLY these people in a given date range.  They might clock into 3 departments, but actually work in 5 so I would need to see that they didn't have time in those 2 departments but that there was work in the work field.

Thoughts?  Ideas?

Thanks for any input!  :)

Example:
[image: Link to Example]

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected result, use http://sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html

Comment: My expected result would be that the Report would show the lines with missing data, but not the lines where they clocked in.

Comment: If "blank" means Null, create a query which selects rows where `[Time Clocked In]` is Null ... like this -> `SELECT * FROM YourTableNameHere WHERE [Time Clocked In] Is Null`  Then use the query as your report's *Record Source*.

Comment: @HansUp - He might need the Nz() function incorporated in there as well.

Comment: I have tried using the Is Null in combination with Is Not Null's, but it's not working right.

My biggest issue is that I need to validate that there are "units processed" in that field with an Is Not Null while also saying that the "Time clocked in" field Is Null.  However, what I forgot to mention in my example is that an ENTIRE ROW could be blank.  If the whole row is nothing but blanks, I have it set up to hide that row b/c the employee spent no time there.  So if I just us an "Is Null" for that field, then those entirely blank rows show up.

Comment: Is there any way in SQL to represent the following: (Field 1 Is Not Null AND Field 2 Is Null) OR (Field 3 Is Not Null AND Field 4 Is Null)?  I just need SQL to associate that Field 1 and Field 2 are linked and that Field 3 and Field 4 are linked in the statement.

Comment: Nevermind, that statement I wrote works...lol
I was trying some other SIMILAR stuff I found on another forum and it didn't work, but what I wrote will work (or at least it looks like it) from my report.  :)

Thank you all for the suggestions and help!  It helped me get to where I needed to be!